# Two .factory error ( angularjs + ionic )

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-factory

I have two .factory with an array each, but throws me an error the second .factory , is like a could not have two .factory

Any help please

Thank

```
.factory('RawData', function() {
    // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

    // Some fake testing data   
    var rawData = [{
      "id": "1",
      "tipo": "evento",
      "titulo": "Esta es una noticia de dos líneas principal",
      "bg": "fondo-not.png",
      "bgdetail": "noti-detalle.png",
      "fec": "ABRIL, 14,  2:56 AM",
      "com": "Backpack from Très Bien. Made in collaboration with Haerfest. Nylon body with top zip closure. Leather bottom. Outer compartment with zip closure and leather trims. Adjustable shoulder straps in leather. Metal hardware. Lined with cotton. Inner compartments. Outer logo branding."
    }];

    return {
        all: function() {
            return rawData;
        },
        get: function(id) {         
            for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {  

                if (parseInt(rawData[i].id) === parseInt(id)) {
                    return rawData[i];                                  
                }
            }           
            return null;
        }
    };
});

.factory('ServicioData', function() {
    // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

    // Some fake testing data   
    var servData = [{
      "id": "1",
      "logo": "logo1.png",
      "titulo": "Restaurante",    
      "com": "Nuestro Menú"
    }];

    return {
        all: function() {
            return servData;
        },
        get: function(id) {         
            for (var i = 0; i < servData.length; i++) { 

                if (parseInt(servData[i].id) === parseInt(id)) {
                    return servData[i];                                 
                }
            }           
            return null;
        }
    };
});
```

Error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   starter due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'starter' is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as
>   the second argument.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/nomod?p0=starter
>       at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost/ionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8346:12)
>       at http://localhost/ionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10050:17
>       at ensure (http://localhost/ionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9974:38)
>       at module (http://localhost/ionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10048:14)
>       at http://localhost/ionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12380:22
>       at forEach (http://localhost/ionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8606:20)
>       at loadModules (http://localhost/ionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12364:5)
>       at createInjector (http://localhost/ionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12290:11)
>       at doBootstrap (http://localhost/ionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9728:20)
>       at bootstrap (http://localhost/ionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9749:12)
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=starter&p1=Error%3…2Flocalhost%2Fionic%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A9749%3A12)

Comment: Show where you are registering the "starter" module, i.e. `angular.module("starter", [...])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the ; after the end of the first factory so you can continue chaining a second one.

```
.factory('RawData', function() {
    // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

    // Some fake testing data   
    var rawData = [{
      "id": "1",
      "tipo": "evento",
      "titulo": "Esta es una noticia de dos líneas principal",
      "bg": "fondo-not.png",
      "bgdetail": "noti-detalle.png",
      "fec": "ABRIL, 14,  2:56 AM",
      "com": "Backpack from Très Bien. Made in collaboration with Haerfest. Nylon body with top zip closure. Leather bottom. Outer compartment with zip closure and leather trims. Adjustable shoulder straps in leather. Metal hardware. Lined with cotton. Inner compartments. Outer logo branding."
    }];

    return {
        all: function() {
            return rawData;
        },
        get: function(id) {         
            for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {  

                if (parseInt(rawData[i].id) === parseInt(id)) {
                    return rawData[i];                                  
                }
            }           
            return null;
        }
    };
})

.factory('ServicioData', function() {
    // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

    // Some fake testing data   
    var servData = [{
      "id": "1",
      "logo": "logo1.png",
      "titulo": "Restaurante",    
      "com": "Nuestro Menú"
    }];

    return {
        all: function() {
            return servData;
        },
        get: function(id) {         
            for (var i = 0; i < servData.length; i++) { 

                if (parseInt(servData[i].id) === parseInt(id)) {
                    return servData[i];                                 
                }
            }           
            return null;
        }
    };
});
```